# Table 100% Width - Issues with Firefox & Safari

Tags: css, firefox, safari

Having some issues with table content set at 100% not rendering properly in Safari(all sorts of weird sizing) and then Firefox(spills over the edge).

Is there a way I can set it to show width:100% for Firefox in TD and max-width:100% in Safari using CSS, this is what seems to fix it when set manually in each using Inspect Element.

After Googling the issue, table 100% width problems does appear problematic for Safari and Firefox browsers.

**Can max-width:100% AND width:100% be both set for an element?**

```
 <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"    style="width:100%">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td><a href="link1"><img src="pic1.jpg" style="border-style:solid; border- width:10px; float:left; max-height:240px; max-width:96%" ></a></td>
 <td><a href="link2"><img src="pic2.jpg" style="border-style:solid; border-width:10px; float:left; max-height:240px; max-width:96%" ></a></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't have Safari here, but I can solve the problems in such a way that the code works the same in Mozilla, Chrome and IE. Hope that helps!

Tables are meant for displaying data. That's what they're designed for; that's what they're good at. So one of their design paradigms is that they don't hide things; if the width would become too narrow to show everything, they ignore the width rules and display everything anyway.

With that in mind, look at what happens in Mozilla. If you have two images side by side that together are wider than the width of the window, the table ignores its `width:100%` rule and just displays the images, no matter what, even at the cost of a horizontal scrollbar.

So, what can you do; you can dispense with the table and just display the images side by side. Make the `a` elements 50% wide, just like the table cells did.

```css
a {
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}
a img {
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:10px;
  max-height:240px;
  box-sizing:border-box; /* to account for the border */
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="link1"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/270/240"/></a>
<a href="link2"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/270/240"/></a>
```